# How should i fix this error i am trying to build an react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tsx

`Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19) at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10) at filename (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:94:23) at I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:122:39 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at asyncGeneratorStep (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:3:103) at _next (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:5:194) at I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:5:364 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:5:97 at handleCache (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:161:18) at I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:216:18 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at asyncGeneratorStep (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:3:103) at _next (I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:5:194) at I:\Web\AquaFrontEnd-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\cache.js:5:364 { opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ], library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'`

i tried node reinstalling and other methods given by chatgpt but it didnt worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.